# We're "graduated" to public beta!

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

If you open the site incognito mode it shows up now :)

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions

[image]

We can celebrate with whatever!

Comment: On a related note, for the moment this knocks everyone out of the rep range to review low quality posts and suggested edits.

Comment: @Andy I'll get there soon enough

Comment: The `Beta` badge told me :P. Congratulations.

Comment: That's great, but do we have a scope yet?

Comment: We are "close enough".  New users will give us a fresh look :).

Answer (score 7):

Yay!

Now comes the tricky bit (I know, a lot of people probably think that we've already passed the tricky bit). I've been through something like six private betas over the last year, including this one (seven if you count the failed Open Science one), and I can say with confidence that there are several issues that we'll encounter within the next few days/weeks/months:

- **Private beta users leaving.** Some folks stick around for the private beta, then leave when the site goes public. This can be for a variety of reasons. One that I've heard often - and that I'm using to explain why my activity on Hardware Recommendations will be decreasing - is simply the problem of time. People have a finite amount of time, and adding helping out on another young, growing site can be a hassle.

  I'll be decreasing my participation because I've done what I came here to do - help the site in its early stages - and because I can't contribute much more in terms of content. I know that there are others who feel the same way. In order to solve this problem, Hardware Recommendations will have to grab more and more users to grow like a healthy site should. I'm not saying that there will be a mass exodus of users from Hardware Recommendations, just that *some* will leave.
- **Publicity.** This is crucial. I really can't emphasize it enough. People have to know about Hardware Recommendations. The typical way is through Community Promotion Ads, which seem to work (though I don't think anyone's tried to prove it). Related communities can also be mined; examples that spring to mind are Software Recommendations (of course) and Super User. Support from outside Stack Exchange is also a possibility.

These are just two of the potential problems that Hardware Recommendations will face. However, I'm optimistic that - as has been the case for many, *many* sites - they will be solved with ease.

May the site enjoy good luck and a bright future!